# Inequality of two sums of powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^N$ have non-negative components.
Is the following implication correct
$$\sum_{i=1}^N a_i \le \sum_{i=1}^N b_i \implies \sum_{i=1}^N {a_i}^k \le \sum_{i=1}^N {b_i}^k$$
for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$?

I haven't been able to find a counter example, but neither have I been able to find a proof.

Comment: This is false. If it were true, then it would imply $$\sum_{i=1}^N a_i = \sum_{i=1}^N b_i \implies \sum_{i=1}^N {a_i}^k = \sum_{i=1}^N {b_i}^k$$ which is false. For example $$3+0+0 \le 1+1+1$$ but $$3^k + 0^k+0^k > 1^k+1^k+1^k$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's false. For example, let $N=2, a_1=0,a_2=10,b_1=5,b_2=5,k=2$. Then, $0+10\leq 5+5$ but $0^2+10^2=100 > 5^2+5^2=50 $. You may be interested in Jensen's inequality and the Generalized Mean inequality.